# How to find the MAC address of Wi-Fi devices connected to socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am developing a web application which acts as a server. In this application I have implimented ServerSocket for two way communication between server application and wi-fi device which acts as client. I am not connecting to my server directly, I am connecting to my router which port forwards to my system and two way communication is successful. All I want now is to find the MAC address of Wi-fi device which is connected.I have done some research and tried to get the MAC address but failed.Can anyone help me on this.Below is the part of my code.

```
public class ScheduleJob extends ServletApp implements Job{

private int port = 1717;
public static String number;
String ReceivedData = "";

public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("Starting ... ");

    ServerSocket Sersocket = null;
    System.out.println("Starting the socket server at port:" +port);
    boolean listeningSocket = true;
    try {
        Sersocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 1717");
    }
    try {

        while (listeningSocket) {
            Socket scokt = Sersocket.accept();
             InetAddress MachineAdd = scokt.getInetAddress();
            System.out.println("Response-----:" +MachineAdd);
            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("current ip : "+ip);
            NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);

            byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();
            System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: I am getting the mac address of my PC instead of Wi-Fi device.

Answer (score 2):

MAC address is piece of information which belongs to [layer 2 of OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_2:_Data_Link_Layer).

In other words it's not preserved whenever you are communicating using L3 protocol (until you are communicating directly via cross cable or via L2 switch).

I would recommend you to send MAC address as a part of your application communication from client to your server, so it will not be lost when your router will do port forwarding.

**Some of already asked questions on this topic:**

- [Why can't the server get the client MAC address, like the client IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854731)
- [How can I get the MAC and the IP address of a connected client in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381)
- [how to get a client's MAC address from HttpServlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839973)

Comment: I have a small doubt. Is there any other things like MAC ID which is unique to every devices and can be read from server side without client sending.

Comment: In L3 communication you only get client IP and TCP port.

Comment: thank you friend. i will try sending MAC Id as a part of communication from client as you said.

Comment: @Arun Don't assume that a MAC address will be unique. It can be easily spoofed.

Comment: ok but is there any thing through which i can detect that the information i receive on server is from a particular client when there are multiple client.