# How can I get mac address of client in LAN using socket communication - C#

Tags: c#, sockets, server, tcp, mac-address

I have system with devices sending information to server by TCP sockets and I want to filter devices by MAC address on server app.

I tried to find possibilities to call on socket method  to get mac address of sender but I dont see in docs. I suspect that C# app doesn't see ethernet layer info.

If I'm right then which way I should go to checking senders?

Thank you

Comment: See this link: [why-cant-the-server-get-the-client-mac-address-like-the-client-ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854731/why-cant-the-server-get-the-client-mac-address-like-the-client-ip)

Comment: communication is only inside LAN - server and clients in the same address pool.

Comment: Sockets don't provide MAC address information. See duplicate for what does.

Comment: See duplicate for what does. ???